# Is it possible to change the font size in SSMS log file viewer?

Tags: query, ssms

I'm using SSMS 18.2 and find that the font size inside the log file viewer window (reachable via "Object Explorer" -> "Management" -> "SQL Server Logs" -> Current") is very small, probably below 8 point.

I have looked at all the font sizes under "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Environment" -> "Fonts and Colors", but cannot find a solution.  After running a query, the font in the Messages tab is small also, but this is not as much of an issue for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I discovered that this was the result of accessing SSMS on a remote desktop from two different clients with different resolutions. Once it's set smaller, it doesn't revert until the system is rebooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you can access the text, you can copy and paste it into a text editor and  upsize it as you wish.
2. You can temporarily reduce the resolution of your monitor.
   From the Windows menu, choose "Settings", the "gear" picture.

[image: Picture of settings button]
and type "Display Settings" in the search, and choose a lower resolution.
A good resolution to try is 1024x768, which used to be a popular video card resolution.

[image: Picture of display resolution drop-down list.]

3. You can use a technology built into windows.
   (you may want to turn your volume off, or mute the sound first).
   In the Control Panel (Large Icons view), run "Ease of Access Center"
   Under the second section, "Explore all settings"
   Click on "Make the computer easier to see"
   There are many strategies you can use to do this.
   Including...
4. [Magnifying Glass](https://www.bing.com/search?q=change%20text%20size%20windows%2010%20site:microsoft.com&form=B00032&ocid=SettingsHAQ-BingIA&mkt=en-US)

Press [Windows-Key]+[Plus-Key]
The magnifying glass tool should pop up.
Mine defaulted to increments of 100%, and I wanted finer control, 
so if you want to do that, click on Options...
[image: Magnifier Settings Window, clicking right-most control, a gear-shape, the Options button.]
...and change the increment to what you like -- I like 10%.
[image: Showing list of choosing increment -- discrete values of 5, 10, 25, 50 %, 100 %, 150, 200, and 400 %]

5. In the Ease of Access Center, if you click on "Change the size of text and icons"

[image: picture of link-like "Change the size of text and icons" button to click on]

Then "Display" comes up and under "Scale and layout" you can "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" to 125% or 150%.

[image: Picture of "Display" settings screen, accessible from the Control Panel]

Your mileage may vary with this option, though, because Microsoft recommends 100%, and different applications seem to respond to this setting in different ways.  I would lean more towards reducing your display resolution than choosing this option.  But it's here, and another thing you can try.